# crop the recorded video - Objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing an app which will record the video with the specified square frame, just same like instagram. But when I record using UIImagePickerController it will record with the full screen, and now I want to crop the video to the square. Please help me to find how to crop the video with some specified frame. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture photo in your defined frame

Checkout following snippet

```
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil] ;
mediaUI.delegate = self;
mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaUI.view.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 310, 280);
[self.view addSubview:mediaUI];
```